ORA-30081 error with Date Parameters arithmetic
I have a query when I want to calculate the number of days between a (user-entered) date range parameters.
SELECT SUM(rt1.PRIMARY_QUANTITY)/(:P_TO_DATE - :P_FROM_DATE) AVERAGE 
  FROM RCV_TRANSACTIONS rt1

This works fine in an 3rd party SQL tool, however in the Oracle BI Publisher Data Model I am getting the error:

ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic

In the above example, say I am using these values for the two parameters:
:P_FROM_DATE = 10/01/2024
:P_TO_DATE = 10/26/2024

Based on the above expression I would expect this to result in a value of 25 (days), that is the number of days between both of these given values.
These parameters are formatted as Date type in the data model:

What do I need to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

First of all, you should be getting ORA-00937: not a single-group group function error.

What I have in the post is the error I am getting.

There is no reason to get a ORA-00937 since the aggregate is the only column of the SELECT. The ORA-30081 is maybe due to NSL settings for dates not being what you think, as long as you don't see the generated SQL it remains difficulty to guess. ORACLE itself doesn't care of the "/" and "-" difference between your input and the expected format, but bi-publisher... ?

Perhaps something like CAST(:P_FROM_DATE as date) to see if the datatype is being lost somewhere in the process

The error suggests it's actually treating the values as timestamps, not dates; that makes the result if the subtraction an interval data type, not a number, and dividing your sum number by an interval would throw ORA-30081. So, casting to date as Connor suggested might work, but it would be better to figure out why the data type is changing.

The CAST function seems to have worked! Thank you Conner and Alex!

Your query always seems to retrieve the total sum of primary quantity and divide it by the number of days in the range. Is that a useful average? I would perhaps expect the query to be select avg(sum(rt1.primary_quantity)) average from rvc_transactions rt1 where trunc(transaction_date) between :p_from_date and :p_to_date group by transaction_date or something along those lines.
